# Upload multiple canvas images through javascript loop

Tags: javascript, php, image, canvas, upload

I am trying to make an upload script which resizes multiple images client side before the *saveimage.php* handles them. The reason for this is because they will be uploaded at an outside location where there might be very slow internet.

I have been able to find pieces of code around here which helped me put it together. I am only a beginner so it's probably very messy!

What it currently does is it checks whenever files are being input in the 'file_input' field. Then it looks at the amount of files and loop through them until every file has been placed in the canvas and upload while it's in there.

**However, the problem is:** when I don't add an alert for each file, the loop goes too fast and only processes 1 or 2 out of 10 images for example. Because the upload script will go faster than the canvas can be updated with a new image.

This is my current page, simplified to the core:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <input id="file_input" type='file' multiple />
</form>

<div id="preview">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script>

    var input = document.getElementById('file_input');
    input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles);

    function handleFiles(e) {

        var files = input.files;
        alert(files.length +" files are being uploaded!"); // display amount of files for testing purpose

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {

            alert("Upload file number: "+i); // display file # for testing purpose, when this is removed the script will go too fast

            var MAX_HEIGHT = 1000;
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image;

            img.onload = function(){
                if(img.height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    img.width *= MAX_HEIGHT / img.height;
                    img.height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                preview.style.width = img.width + "px";
                preview.style.height = img.height + "px";
                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

                // the canvas should contain an image now and this will send it through saveimage.php
                var myDrawing = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var drawingString = myDrawing.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
                var postData = "canvasData="+drawingString;
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.open("POST",'saveimage.php',true);
                ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');
                ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
                    {
                        if (ajax.readyState == 4);
                    }
                    ajax.send(postData);
            };

            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[i]);
        }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my *saveimage.php* which works well, but just for the complete overview:

```
<?php

if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    $rawImage=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
    $removeHeaders=substr($rawImage, strpos($rawImage, ",")+1);
    $decode=base64_decode($removeHeaders);

    // check if the file already exists and keep adding +1 intil it's unique
    $i = 1;
    while(file_exists('uploads/image'.$i.'.jpg')) {           
        $i++;
    }

    $fopen = fopen( 'uploads/image'.$i.'.jpg', 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fopen, $decode);
    fclose( $fopen );

}

?>
```

**A bit of extra information:**

- I have added canvas, because as far as I can understand that's the
  only way to resize images client side. In the final script it will be
  set to hidden.
- If the canvas could be skipped and the data sent to *saveimage.php*
  immediately then that would solve the problem too I think.
- As I said I am not very experienced with javascript, so if there is a
  much simpler way to achieve this goal. Please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before doing anything else : set the onload handler *before* setting the src.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I have placed the onload handler before the src now, it still seems to function the same way, what is the reason for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript loads image asynchronously. That means once it is assigned a new image's .src it will begin loading the image but will simultaneously continue processing the javascript after the .src while the image takes time to load.

You're using the same image variable (`var img`) inside your for loop. Therefore, each time through the loop you are overwriting the previous img before the previous image has been fully loaded.

Here's an image loader that fully loads all image and then calls the start() function where you can do you processing:

```
// image loader

// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
imageURLs.push("myImage1.png");
imageURLs.push("myImage2.png");
// etc, etc.

// the loaded images will be placed in imgs[]
var imgs=[];

var imagesOK=0;
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onload callback use the `this` keyword(instead of `img`) to for the current image, `img` may/will be overwritten in the for loop before the callback fires.
`img.height --> this.height` etc
Also is there a reason you're using a custom content type instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?
Url encoded form data is much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same problem for some time now, but I finally 
cobbled together another solution, using bits of code from others, who have addressed this problem, 
and it works. It may not be perfect, and I would welcome any improvement suggestions.
The concept is that you have two Javascript 
Functions, which are identicle called Resize0 and Resize1, and they call each other 
until all photos have been resized then the Function which resizes the
last image Submits the Form. The two Functions pass parameters between 
each other so that one of them will know when to Submit the Form. 
Two of those parameters are, Number_Of_Images and current Image_Number.
You can also download a working Example Web page from 
http://www.wantitconsulting.co.nz/ExampleResizeUpload.zip .
You will need to create a folder in the base directory of your test web site 
for the Images to go into. The foldername is TestResizeUpload. The Server 
side uses php.